# Extract all <p> from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

i have not found a solution here on stackoverflow.
So my HTML snippet is:

```
<d1>
<dt class="abc">Test</dt><dd><dl>
    <dt>Part1</dt><dd><p>THISISWHATINEED<br /><a href="anyurl" target="">12334</a><br /><a href="anyurl" target="">abcdef</a></p></dd>
    <dt>Part2</dt><dd><p>THISISWHATINEED2<br /><a href="anyurl" target="">12334</a><br /><a href="anyurl" target="">abcdef</a></p></dd>
<dt class="abc">Test2</dt><dd><dl>
    <dt>Part3</dt><dd><p>THISISWHATINEED3<br /><a href="anyurl" target="">12334</a><br /><a href="anyurl" target="">abcdef</a></p></dd>
    <dt>Part4</dt><dd><p>THISISWHATINEED4<br /><a href="anyurl" target="">12334</a><br /><a href="anyurl" target="">abcdef</a></p></dd>
```

So how do i get all the `<p>` that fit to for example `<dt class="abc">Test</dt><dd><dl>`. I tried to use `d1.find_all("dt")`, but then i am missing the `<p>`. I seriously don't get the way how to get the "childs". Best thing would be to iterate over the `<dt>` and then inside of it over the `<p>` of for example "Test" (the first part). But how do i do that? Do you guys have any tips or ideas?

What i already tried:

```
        d1 = soup.find_all("dl")
        for child in d1.children:
            print(child)
```

And about a lot of other stuff which is not in my head anymore..

Another approach working quite good:

```
            for child in d1.children:
                if child.string is not None:
                    continue
                if child.string is None:
                    xx= len(child.find_all("p"))
```

Thanks!

Greetings
Nick

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Is this the entire HTML? or there's more on the page?

Comment: There is more on the page, but i simplified it so it is easier to understand my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [adjecent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`) CSS selector, which will select one element that *immediately* follows another one.

To use a CSS selector, use the [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `find_all()`.

In your example:

```
for tag in soup.select(".abc +dd dt +dd p"):
    print(tag.contents[0])
```

- `.abc` is the class-name, so replace `abc` with the actual class
- Since there are multiple attributes within the `<p>` tag, use `.contents[0]` to get the desired element

Output:

```
THISISWHATINEED1
THISISWHATINEED2
THISISWHATINEED3
THISISWHATINEED4
```